# Https port not working on 2083 port

Tags: ssl, cpanel

Ive installed cent os, cpanel, registered a domain, activated https and all working fine at my site: h

> https:// mydomain.com (good)

but when

> https:// mydomain.com/cpanel

or

> https:// mydomain.com:2083

https is not working, not securing.

Do I need to reconfigure, or do I need another ssl certificate..?

Comment: Consider asking your question on http://serverfault.com/.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issues with the server firewall. Please try to stop iptables on your server and try to access your cPanel URL.